# Printing issue when the "No Printer" option is selected

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports for printing orders to a KOT printer. I have four different KOT printers. The items are printed according to the corresponding printer names assigned.

This works fine, but in order to increase the speed of printing I checked the "No printer" option. Then prints are coming to only one printer. When it is unchecked the problem is solved.

Code:

```
strSQL = ""
Dim crptDV As New ReportDocument()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, gblCon)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)
Dim path As String
path = Application.StartupPath
crptDV.Load(path & "\reports\rptItemOrder.rpt")
crptDV.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
Dim parameter As New ParameterField                   
parameter = crptDV.ParameterFields("CompanyName")
parameter.CurrentValues.AddValue(CompName)
crptDV.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName
crptDV.Close()
crptDV.Dispose()
```

Comment: Why not write the orders to a text file and send the file to the printer without using crystal report

Comment: It was a good suggestion,I am using a lot of formulas, So I cannot avoid crystal reports

Comment: I'm not clear on the desired outcome from your question. Also, can you show a snippet from the code you already have for printing? I have been able to print to named printers (even with the no printer option checked)

Comment: Did you check "No printer" option to print fast? So, when is unchecked, your 4 KOT printers work well but not faster as you want?

Comment: @reckface please check the edited question

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to print to all 4 printers? If so, use the crptDV.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName to assign the name of any of the 4 printers.

Comment: @reckface The print will go to different printers when the no printer option is unchecked..Otherwise it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

**Crystal Report "No Printer" option**

The 'No printer' option is when we need to view or print a Crystal Report in a web environment.

Checking the 'No Printer' option tells the report not to get associated with a particular printer and thus it picks up the settings from the report settings or the settings provided from the code.

If the No Printer is no cheked the report picks up the printer settings from the available printer from the developer machine and when it's send to a different printer it messes up the output sometime.

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Comment: @sarath for what I understand selecting the "No Printer" option doesn't improve the printing time. It use the default settings defined in the report, in the default printer defined in your pc.